# Excel For loop and general vba guidance

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to figure out why this button is giving a runtime error '424'. I do not understand if it is the for loop that is throwing it off. I have tried replacing the .activate with .select and nothing happened.

```
Private Sub updateX_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long
Dim emptyRowX As Long
Dim counter

Sheets("Master Inventory").Activate
Sheets("X").Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Master Inventory").Range("A:A")) + 1
emptyRowX = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("X").Range("A:A")) + 1

For counter = 1 To emptyRow
    If MI.Cells(counter, 1).Value = "X" Then
    X.Cells(emptyRowX, 1).Value = MI.Cells(counter, 2).Value
    X.Cells(emptyRowX, 2).Value = MI.Cells(counter, 3).Value
    X.Cells(emptyRowX, 3).Value = MI.Cells(counter, 4).Value
    X.Cells(emptyRowX, 4).Value = MI.Cells(counter, 5).Value
    X.Cells(emptyRowX, 5).Value = MI.Cells(counter, 6).Value
    End If
Next counter

End Sub
```

Comment: What's `MI` and `X`?

Answer (score 0):

What about following corrections:

```
Dim counter As Long <-- this you already have (but you forgot the type definition)

Dim MI As Worksheet, X As Worksheet

Set MI = Worksheets("Master Inventory")
Set X = Worksheets("X")

Sheets("Master Inventory").Activate <-- this you already have
```

Comment: When implementing these corrections the following error occurred. Runtime error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: @BigBen: answer edited again, now it should be perfect :-)